# More than one list view in a Activity. Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-animation

I was looking through some apps in android like the gdocs, catch apps for android. They have a list view where they display the list of all items. However they also have a swipe action where if you swipe to left or right it takes you to a filtered list of items. I mean if the user is in the main list of all documents, and if he swipes left he can go to the favorite list of items, and if he swipes back right he can go back to the complete list of items.

Does anyone know how is this implemented? Is it done using only one listview, or is it done by many list view? As far as I know it is difficult to have more than one listview in a activity, If tried to have more than one there are some serious force closes happening in my app. Is it really possible to have two listviews in a single activity? Does anyknow know about it? Is there any sample that is having a similar implementation? I would like to see a sample where the swipe left and swipe right takes them to a different list view with in the same activity. The animation looks as if the swipe left and swipe right is done using a view flipper. Please let me know if anyone know any kind of details about this. It would be very helpful for me. Thank you in advance for your time and advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple ListViews in one activity without serious problems :).

Such kind of apps, as far as I can guess, implement it with a ViewFlipper with swipe actions and some animations of course.

Here is an example.
http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/03/multiple-listview-and-custom-listview.html

Comment: In that case what will happen if I use the function ListView lstView = getListView(); in my on create of activity? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: If you have to have multiple ListViews, then you should be extending the Activity class, instead of the ListActivity class. ListActivity is just a specialized Activity which helps you when you have only one ListView.

Comment: Oh K. Thank you very much for that. I was not aware of that we can have a list view within a Activity instead of a List Activity? Is there any drawback of using just the Activity instead of List Activity?

Comment: Nope. Just that you will have to do a little bit of more code like inflating your listviews.

Answer (score 0):

I would speculate, that there is one list per activity, 
and swiping action just calls up another activity.

It is possible to have more that one list - your "forcecloses" certainly have nothing to do with this